# Play piano vs. play the piano

Tags: articles

When I describe my hobbies, should I write

> I play piano

or

> I play **the** piano

Are both forms acceptable? And how would you handle the phrase

> I am an amateur musician, playing the saxophone, guitar and piano.

Should there be three "the" or only one? or none?

Comment: Since your question is about the use of articles, and since I see no prepositions in your sentences, I changed the tag for you. Feel free to roll back the edit if you _do_ want to ask something about prepositions instead :)

Comment: Indeed, sorry :)

Comment: As an Englishman, omitting the article, per your example "I play piano", sounds *very* American to my ear.

Comment: [Language log discussed the similar issue of the difference *playing a violin* and *playing the violin*](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2020), which are both correct and have subtly different meanings.

Comment: @568ml: Switching between [US/UK corpuses in Google NGramns](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+play+piano%2CI+play+the+piano&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20play%20piano%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20play%20the%20piano%3B%2Cc0) doesn't suggest the more recent but still less common "article-less" usage is any more or less likely to occur on either side of the pond. It certainly has no particularly "American" edge to me - but I do kinda feel "professional" musicians are probably the main ones promoting the usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are acceptable, but saying "I play the piano" sounds a bit better. The same goes for the other instruments as far as I am concerned.

Comment: So you would write "... playing the saxophone, the guitar and the piano"?

Comment: Yes definitely. "He plays saxophone", "I love playing guitar" etc... But as I said, the other is definitely not incorrect. "He plays the saxophone" sounds all right too. Especially if the context were: "What instrument does he play?" "He plays the saxophone".

Comment: @yohbs: It's entirely a stylistic choice whether you include the article at all in your "three-instrument" example. And if you *do* decide to use it (I personally normally wouldn't), it's again purely a style issue as to whether to repeat the article every time (and again, I normally wouldn't).